# Syntax error removing duplicate lines via awk '!x[$0]++' file

Tags: awk, solaris

The file contains

```
cat file
a
b
c
b
d
```

Trying to remove duplicate lines on SunOS via

```
awk '!x[$0]++' file
```

(as found in another postings) results in a syntax error

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Works with GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1. Have you tried a space between `!` and `x`?

Comment: On Solaris, use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. `/bin/awk` shouldn't be used, it's the one from the 70s. Generally on Solaris, you want to do `PATH=$(getconf PATH):$PATH` to have sane versions of the utilities.

Comment: /usr/xpg4/bin/awk works. Thank you.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm deleting answer and comments as I have no means to test this. If I'm _that_ wrong, this is the better way.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Could you please formally answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` was first released in the late 70s in Unix V7.

Since then, it has undergone significant changes, some of them not backward compatible.

The GNU `awk` manual has [a very informative section on the subject](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Language-History.html).

Like for many other utilities, Solaris (contrary to most other Unices) has taken the stance of sticking with the older obsolete implementation for its default `awk` utility, and make the newer versions available either under a different name (`nawk`) or at a different location (`/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`, that one not available by default in some stripped-down configurations of Solaris 11).

On Solaris, if you use the default environment, you generally get utilities that behave in an ancient/obsolete way. For instance, before Solaris 11, `sh` in the default environment would not be a standard shell, but a Bourne shell. A lot of other utilities (`grep`, `sed`, `tail`, `df`...) are not POSIX compliant, not even to the 1992 version of the standard.

Solaris is a POSIX (even Unix) certified system (at least in some configurations), however POSIX/Unix only requires a system be compliant in a given (documented) environment (which may not be the default).

So, when you write code that needs to be portable to Solaris, you need either to write in a syntax from another age, or make sure you put yourself in a POSIX environment.

How to do so for a given version of those standards is documented in the `standards(5)` man page on Solaris.

So, for `awk` here, you can use:

```
awk 'x[$0]++ == 0'
```

Which would work in the 1978 `awk` from Unix v7 and Solaris `/bin/awk` (in the original `awk`, you could not use any arbitrary expression as a *pattern*, it had to be conditions using relational operators like `==` here).

Or:

```
nawk '!x[$0]++'
```

Or:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk '!x[$0]++'
```

Or more generally, to have saner (and more portable) versions of all the utilities (including `awk`):

```
PATH=`getconf PATH`:$PATH export PATH
: ^ false || exec sh "$0" ${1+"$@"} # rexec with POSIX sh if we're
                                    # a Bourne shell
awk '!x[$0]++'
```

Both `/usr/bin/getconf PATH` and `/usr/xpg4/bin/getconf PATH` will give you a `$PATH` like: `/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin`, which will get you XPG4 (a superset of POSIX.1-1990, POSIX.2-1992, and POSIX.2a-1992) conformance. On Solaris 11, you also have a `/usr/xpg6/bin/getconf` which will get you a `PATH` like `/usr/xpg6/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/SUNWspro/bin` for XPG6 (SUSv3, superset of POSIX 2001) conformance (where it conflicts with XPG4, in practice unlikely to affect you).

Comment: `x[$0]++ == 0` worked with heirloom `oawk`, isn't it original awk?

Comment: @cuonglm, that's a port of (Open)Solaris /bin/awk, so yes, not much different from the original awk like Solaris' /bin/awk. As I said, `x[$0]++ == 0` should work with every awk including the original one on Unix V7 (tested on a PDP11 emulator with the V7 images from the Unix Heritage Society).